# Use for loop variable as dictionary key in Django template

Tags: django, templates, variables, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to get the following working.

The count loop needs to loop through for all values, and there may not be a user associated with each count, but the count value `i` needs to be used in each loop to pass to the JavaScript.

python part:

```
users = {}
users[1]={}
users[1][id]=...
users[1][email]=...

...

count=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Django template part:

```
{% for i in count %}
do some stuff with the value i using {{i}} which always returns the value, i.e. 1

email:{% if users.i.email %}'{{users.i.email}}'{% else %}null{% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns nothing for email.
When I substitute the number `1` for `i` in `{% if user.i.email %}` email returns the users email address.
I'm using the data in JavaScript, so it needs to be implicitly null if it doesn't exist.
I can't seem to get Django to recognize the `i` variable as a variable instead of the value i.

using `[]` doesn't work, as it throws an invalid syntax error

```
email:{% if users.[i].email %}'{{users.[i].email}}'{% else %}null{% endif%}
```

I have tried using "`with`" statement

```
{% for i in count %}{% with current_user=users.i %}...
```

and then using `current_user.email`, but returned nothing

Have also tried

```
{% for i in count %}{% with j=i.value %}...
```

just in case it would work, and then trying to use `j`, but same result.

I have thought about creating an inner for loop that loops over the user object and check if i is equal to the key/value, but that seems expensive and not very scalable.

Any ideas how I can force Django to view `i` as a variable and use it's value as an index, or any other way get around this?

Thanks

Jayd

***Edit:**

I tried the extra for loop, as suggested by Abhi, below.

```
{% for i in count %}
  {% for key, current_user in users.items %}
      do some stuff with the value i using {{i}} which always returns the value, i.e. 1
      email:{% if i == key and current_user.email %}'{{current_user.email}}'{% else %}null{% endif%}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This sort of works, but now it will repeat `do some stuff with the value i` for every value of users. and if I put in an if:

```
{% for i in count %}
  {% for key, current_user in users.items %}
    {% if i == key %}
      do some stuff with the value i using {{i}} which always returns the value, i.e. 1
      email:{% if i == key and current_user.email %}'{{current_user.email}}'{% else %}null{% endif%}
    {% endif%}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That ignores the loops when a count doesn't have a particular user.

The only way I can see around this is the have the user loop at each place that I want to use `current_user`.

```
{% for i in count %}
      do some stuff with the value i using {{i}} which always returns the value, i.e. 1
      email:{% for key, current_user in users.items %}{% if i == key and current_user.email %}'{{current_user.email}}'{% else %}null{% endif%}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this seems very expensive to do.
Any ideas?

I was thinking of maybe writing a filter that returns the values for users using `i` as the key:

```
{% with current_user=users|getuser:i %}
```

But I don't know if this will work or I will get the same error, where `i` is being passed as the value 'i' instead of a variable name.

I will give it a try so long.

***Edit**

This didn't work.
The  filter worked using `{{}}` returning the object, but it didn't work inside the `{% %}`
.

Thanks for the input

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary for the outer collection instead of a list?

Comment: Why did you use **bold** formatting throughout this question, instead of following the clear formatting prompts to the right of the edit box?

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I didn't see the prompts when I made the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with the following as a work around:

This is the filter code:

```
@register.filter(name='dict_value_or_null')
def dict_value_or_null(dict, key):
    if key in dict:
        return dict[key]
    else:
        return 'null'
```

Here is the template code

```
{% for i in count %}
      do some stuff with the value i using {{i}} which always returns the value, i.e. 1
      email:'{{users|dict_value_or_null:i|dict_value_or_null:'email'}}'
{% endfor %}
```

This works well, so I suppose that have my solution. But I still think this all could have been much easier if there was a way in the template system to force values inside {% %} to be treated as variables, instead of literals.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the input

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but you could take a look at Jinja2 for your templating engine.  It plugs into Django fairly well, has a very similar syntax, but is designed a little better (IMHO) especially when it comes to being able to use Python-like constructs in your templates.

Answer (score 9):

As Joe says in his comment, a dictionary is clearly the wrong data structure for the outer container. You should be using a list.

```
users = []
user = {'id':..., 'email': ...}
users.append(user)
```

...

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need the number of each user within the loop, you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.

Comment: I need to have the count start at 1, which is why I used a separate count list, and also some counts will exist that don't have users associated with them. So there might only be 2 users and I might need to loop and do the other things with the count number 6 or 8 times.

Comment: @Jayd Still not sure I fully understand the use case, but these are details that would have been good to put in the question upfront so we know what real problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% for key,val in user.items %}
ID is {{ val.id }} and Email is {{ val.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note- You've used the dictionary "users" at the top and user[i] in an attempt to access index i. Ensure that the dictionary names match up when you try to access user.items

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Yes, this is the work around that I was talking about, having a for loop inside the other for loop. It has worked in the code, but is there any other way to do this that doesn't require loops in loops, but rather to call the users object by i?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on user and users. I went back and changed it.

Answer (score 1):

to make Jayd Code usable with either list or dict, try this

```
@register.filter(name='dict_value_or_null')
def dict_value_or_null(dict, key):
    try:
        return dict[key]
    except:
        return 'null'
```